# how to register this offline wallet in sign up?

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-registration

here is my view.py

```
from models import Balance
def profile(request):
    user = Balance.objects.get(user=request.user)
    return render(request,'profile.html',{"balance":user.balance})
```

and created model here

```
class Balance(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    balance = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

here is my registration and i think i have made mistake here:

```
@unauthenticated_user
def register(request):
    form = CreateUser()

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CreateUser(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():

        form.save()
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        instance = Balance(user=request.user, balance=0)
        instance.save()

        messages.success(request, "Congrats !!" + username + "now you are member of the society")
        return redirect('login')
context = {'form': form}

return render(request, "register.html", context)
```

I am able fetch the balance of the user in from the database at the time of showing the profile but not able save it into database while registration. As erorr returns:

> ValueError at /register/
> Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x7f98c64caa60>>": "Balance.user" must be a "User" instance

Answer (score 4):

Your user is not signed in when you write this line:

```
instance = Balance(user=request.user, balance=0)
```

I assume your form `CreateUser` works properly. when a form is saved it returns the created instance so you can use it instead of `request.user`:

```
user = form.save()
instance = Balance(user=user, balance=0)
instance.save()
```

Comment: yes! It worked for me, and thank you for the instant response.